# How to get navigation and backbutton side by side in android

Tags: android

```
----------------
| <- =         |
----------------

<- back
=  navigation toggle button
```

I tried to add back button to the navihgation drawer but I am not able to add so

I want both the button simulteneously

Comment: your image is not displaying

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @NileshRathod https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357690/imgur-returning-503-service-unavailable

Comment: update your image again

Comment: @MikeM. please check the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctV78.jpg

Comment: @NileshRathod Yeah, imgur's having problems, atm. That's what that meta post is about.

Comment: Use a toolbar... Add 2 buttons in it and toggle the behaviour  in code

Answer (score 1):

try this use custom `Toolbar`

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ar_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_drawericon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

than set click listener to this `imageview` in your activity like this

```
Toolbar toolbar;
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ar_toolbar);
        ImageView backIMG =(ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.img_back);
        ImageView drawerIMG =(ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.img_drawericon);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        backIMG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(ReferralsActivity.this, "Back arrow clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        drawerIMG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(ReferralsActivity.this, "Drawer icon clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but what about toggle animation